# findViewById returns null after setting XML value instead of hard coded value in one of XML files

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm new to Android programming and I have a very strange problem. I have a few .xml files containing layer-lists with shape inside (I use them for buttons' background) and every file is very similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
            android:bottom="-7dp"
            android:left="-7dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="-7dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#FFFF0000" />

            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

            <padding android:left="0dp"
                     android:right="0dp"
                     android:top="0dp"
                     android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Now when I replace value of    `android:width`    in stroke with value defined in separate `dimens.xml` file (in res/values directory) like that: `android:width="@dimen/grid_thickness"`, save it, compile (without errors) and run on my device whole applications crashes. I found out that it crashes because suddenly `findViewById` method (called after `setContentView`) in onCreate method of my activity returns null.

I spent hours on this problem and I am sure that changing "2dp" with "@dimen/grid_thickness" is a reason of returning null from findViewById method. **Apparently changing it back is not enough. I have to delete whole `dimens.xml` file to make my application work again.** This is very strange.

Here is my haunted `dimens.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="grid_thickness">2dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And here is a code of onCreate method (NullPointerException is thrown at the last line):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerText);
    header.setText("sometext");
}
```

I also tried reaching other views with same result. Everything works without that dimens.xml, so a problem is not in activity code in my opinion.

And here is a fragment of my main.xml file where I reach that layer-list:

```
<package.path.ClassExtendingButton
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="   "
        android:background="@drawable/border_ul_corner"
        android:id="@+id/field0" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" android:onClick="makeMove" android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" android:paddingBottom="30dp"/>
```

I reach it in `android-background` attribute.

Stacktrace from logcat:

```
03-20 18:04:53.959    8903-8903/pum.l2.zad1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pum.l2.zad1, PID: 8903
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pum.l2.zad1/pum.l2.zad1.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at pum.l2.zad1.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As I said before: NullPointerException is being thrown after trying to reach method of something returned from findViewById (it can be anything, I tried many different views from my layout).

I am using IntelliJ Idea 14.0.3 and 19 Android API version. I heard that there are some bugs related to Android in this version of my IDE. Maybe this is a reason?

Comment: Please post your code where the error occurs.

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but is there any way you can include R.layout.main? Or at least the snippet where you're referencing the layer-list?

Comment: Yes of course. Done.

Comment: Post logcat showing the stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: Done. [putting random characters]

Comment: OK, so what is line 66 of `MyActivity.java`?

Comment: As I said 2 times... It is reaching of method of something that was returned from findViewById. Look at the code of onCreate method. As I said there: "NullPointerException is thrown at the last line" (I meant line before '}' char of course)

Comment: In your xml is there a text view with id R.id.headerText? I can't find that in the xml you have posted. Is it a different xml? If yes please post even that.

Comment: It is not a different xml file. I was just asked to provide a fragment of my layout where I reference layer-list. I will repeat it one more time: it doesn't matter which view I try to reach with findViewById. Everyone will be null when "@dimen/grid_thickness" is set. Otherwise whole application will work perfectly.

Comment: Try changing `<dimen name="grid_thickness">2dp</dimen>` to `<dimen name="grid_thickness">2.0dp</dimen>` (notice float value rather than int). It probably won't make a difference though.